# Provisioning profile. "MY BUNDLE ID" doesn't include signing certificate iPhone Distributio: "my name"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios

Hi im having this error for over 3 days and everything i'v tried didnt work...

Im using xcode 9.4 and i used react native to develop my app.

here is screenshot of my error:
[image]

Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@T.sagiv

i am not sure what is your problem , a screen shot like the one you attached is not enough to know the cause of this issue , however , it seems that you have not created distribution profile under your developer account for that application. well , at-least that what the picture is saying .

A Production Certificate and Distribution Provisioning Profile go together when submitting your App to the App Store. A Distribution Provisioning Profile means that you do not need to add a device identifier to the Provisioning Profile... since it's intended use is through the App Store.

A Development Provisioning Profile is intended only for testing. If you're using it for any other purpose you're breaking the agreement.
Apple Store Approval and Apple Store Publishing are essentially the same thing. You get approval to get into the store.

A Distribution Provisioning Profile won't do you any good outside the store.
However, this all applies to a Individual Membership in the developer program.

To resolve this issue , assuming that you are going for production mode , 
you have to Generate the Distribution Certificate & Provisioning Profile for you application .It's going to be so much text on this post to explain everything for you in details , so i prefer you watch this video on youtube [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh2nnjttOwo) to see it ,

you will need to do this on your MAC , windows will not be able to generate the necessary files smoothly.

if you dont have MAC PC , you will need to use openSSL tool , i have used it before under windows OS and i uploaded my app to apple store successfully  .

i hope my post and this video will help you ,

Comment: here is a nice video for doing that under windows OS   through that OpenSSl which i mention earlier , 

please watch this video for more info 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2PB3egShMU

Comment: Thanks man! The first video helped me a lot! I realized that my Distribution Provisioning Profile was invalid. Thanks a lot man you saved me!

Comment: no worries bro , we are always here to help each other  , just promise you will help me next time i ask a question :p 
just one more last advice , make sure you have wrote privacy agreement and you fulfill the apple legal requirements within you application  , to avoid rejection during upload process 
have a good day and good luck whatever you are doing ,