# Why my app immediately quit after open in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I installed Xcode(9.4.1) from App Store and create a iphone simulator.
After that I tried to install some .ipa(https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/tree/master/Crackmes/iOS) app to it but it immediately quit when I opened it.
I tried couple app but the error is the same But when I wrote sample app on Xcode and build to my simulator it run very well.

Even if I try another iphone simulator or reinstall Xcode, I still get same error.

Comment: What version of the relevant SDK do you have installed? You can find out with `xcodebuild -showsdks`.

Comment: iOS SDKs:
 iOS 11.4                       -sdk iphoneos11.4

iOS Simulator SDKs:
 Simulator - iOS 11.4           -sdk iphonesimulator11.4

Comment: Hmm, then the SDK should be supported, and there shouldn't be any problems. I'd recommend trying to reset the simulator's settings under: `"Simulator" -> "Reset contents and settings"`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find where is the error located in your application , 
here is a link reference explaining about how to find the cause error 
also it will explain the most common mistakes in xbasic

[click here](https://codewithchris.com/xcode-errors/)

Comment: my case not in that post. I installed an app from .ipa file not from the source.

Comment: then obviously provision profile is missing ..  is it on store apple ?

Comment: check my post in other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022844/provisioning-profile-my-bundle-id-doesnt-include-signing-certificate-iphone/52022904#52022904

Comment: the one you are using already compiled , but the one you made in your xcode its still within the xcode  you can run it as source code , but as for ipa files it will be generated , but it will not work until you make developer / distribution  provision profile